# Setting attributes on store level in Magento

Tags: magento

I am trying to get Magento to set product attribute values on store views to be the same as the default values.

I have the following code called by an observer on

```
catalog_product_save_before

public function translateProduct($observer)
{
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->getId());

    foreach (Mage::app()->getWebsites() as $website) {
        foreach ($website->getGroups() as $group) {
            foreach ($group->getStores() as $store) {
                $config = $store->getConfig('myconfig');
                if($config['enabled']) {
                    foreach($product->getAttributes() as $attribute) {
                        if($attribute->getBackendType() == 'text' && $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product) != '') {
                            $product->setStoreId($store->getId())->setData($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product));
                        }
                    }
                }                
            }
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

I know my code and loops are being called as I did

```
echo 'Here'; die();
```

through the loop to test it.

Is this the correct way to set data for Magento products across multiple store views or have I gone wrong somewhere?

Thanks in advance for any help/tips/pointers :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whoa there fella.

You need only set your data at the default level. If an attribute value is not set for a store context it will be inferred from the default.

:-)

Comment: Let's say that by somehow the `name` value of a product in the default level is different from that in the Store level. Now if I want to make the store level `name` value same as that of the default level, what will I need to do?

Comment: Just edit it via the admin? The first column is default, the additional columns are for your store views. No need for an extension or any code, what you are trying to do is native ...

Comment: @Ben & @sonassi - No offense, but I actually want the value of `name` in the store level same as the value of `name` in the default level, by using the code. This is because all of these will work using API. **I've still not been able to find a proper solution to this problem, only when the store level `name` value is different from the default level `name` value, and I want both of them to be same again. I'm extremely sorry, but please don't ask why, please!**

Answer (score 3):

To "Use Default" programmatically, set the data for the attribute to FALSE.

```
$product->setStoreId($store->getId())->setData($attribute->getAttributeCode(), FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example above you set the attributes on "storeview"-level, not really on "store" ... it is a bit confusing in magento ...